# Calculate cartesian coordinates of geographical points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have 2 points expressed in `(latitude,longitude)` and I want to calculate the angle with respect to the north pole.

Since the two points are very near (like hundred of meters), is it possible to consider the two points in the cartesian system simply as:

```
x=longitude
y=latitude
```

Then, simply applying $\arctan(y/x)$, I get the angle from the equator.

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you clarify which angle you are interested in?

Comment: With arctan(y/x) i get the angle from the equator and from it then i calculate the angle from the north pole (the socalled bearing)

Comment: Longitude and latitude are already angles. Latitude measures the angle from the equator to your point already. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#/media/File:FedStats_Lat_long.png)

Comment: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Okay, but since the geographic area i'm interested in is very small, is it ok to use the approximation i writed ?

Comment: Try arctan2(cos(delta x), delta y), it is an approximation that will give you the bearing directly. You can't calculate a bearing directly in that coordinate system, because that map projection (simple cylindrial, or Plate Carree) distorts angles, and also distances along parallels.